# what does 麻理 mean?

Tags: words

See the final few seconds of this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AUFzK2WL6Y

to see 「ぼくは麻理 のなか」

I am in ... what?

Comment: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%BC%E3%81%8F%E3%81%AF%E9%BA%BB%E7%90%86%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8B - http://recochoku.jp/news/191195/

Answer (score 1):

麻里（マリ）would be the name of the girl.